# How to maintain optional arguments in mapped typescript function signature

Tags: typescript, variadic, mapped-types

I'm trying to author a typesafe version of the classic `promisify` function. See my [playground link here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-kwBhZazUagQeDUbbFa0Nbo6noAcgYmSdcClUG+OUkiDgGUkkjgluApeYIOoReAdEjKAAhBLjQNhqNypUi6Ca4gptDWPKhA61XB8j1B8wst0bvcNEL7gHW8GpdQZUxXalw0IeFBFYUVW0nRrJH0Z3O6IaV8a90ovsBfTk+nuZhpXe7dC769uGL2o-2RrBnAAC+15BosYFASBpwgdERjMiyeDSAAyngKG8gyxhrhuVAyg0mQAPJaIuaxaho1DJCU3Q8EIM4aH03QUVRNFQLueaKBo0h5tAMzEEQ2gQGwmB8UQM5anAADUcAAIzgTh8B4TABHUMRwCLkMaxFBC4yIAM9bKURJGzncUzGEpKlqRpfQAKxTMwHQ0H0fSMJRJRyKJmhUSQxCkAAbDMoZeSUwgMBcqBuaxLZGNh0qKQZKl4JaECLg8cDkcFrF0Ux6V0JSzHUbRObJDRBVZRQHFcTxUCeYJwmeeJACy1gdMwkCWlqQgAExTEIzWte1nVwAAzFM8lxQgCWZElKUmfcmlKp2un6fh03JalZlGBZa2zZeQx9D1DntE5Ll5XRJXAB5JBEHlPmkAALHAABkT3FTRd1wAAnIF-K3VG9JZBdILfHA3Sxu0SwRSxPDRbF67xat6rrXNdCEWA8CkBlkVFfRuX5ZlOMXZxBNsRVUDE9xxQ1ddcB1SJNNNS17RtRAHXWN1Y2nApk2IzNqVozAC2FEt3YrYZSO7cKAubdtEv8+j+2HY51DOYwZ1vZdnm3b5D3Pa9gPvTrX0-WynIchroUk0I3RInAdC6qk9LvdjvAAD5wJkCScBwwCYPBiFkKh6GYfBcMbsqsDHvkp5rKO2b4BQtSuH+taMHI-TypMy5BtzYOqKQLBDsKCi9ngQHczAZakHniAs2AfTgSaPx-EwNdCJXIIMKeDglxGcWwacMTgHEkNwE0ZEwsKGgAWnnkAacsTmOFY8tG0XTdCQnzu85uNNHPtabYs29ancAAM0+1tlGh7zTAGH3Ax+wuffZCLCMkX4IOY5Tf-F9vfj9nw-q-O478X7A1uF1IBX9r7UH3v2Le6UT63GfgBYBtxQGoPAZAsBsJhpQN3rA2+B8EHOSflAt+5C7jYMwbgyhtx7r4O-oQ3+d89BAA).

Node.js style callbacks *generally* have the form of `(value?: ValueType, err?: ErrorType)`. Of course, they can also have an inner variadic form, such as `(a?: A, b?: B, ..., n?: N, err?: Error)`. Covering the first form is easy. Covering the latter, I've found, is difficult.  Why?

Well, I'm finding that type inference doesn't work well with optional arguments.

1. First, to get the parameters of the node callback, I used `Parameters<MyCallbackType>`,
2. Second, I try and get all inferred callback params *up to last param*, omitting the the `err?: Error` arg. I'm calling the slice of the array that includes everything but the tail `Body`, and defining it as: `export type Body<T> = T extends [...infer B, infer _TailEl] ? B : never;`

But... `Body<T>` doesn't work great when there are optional items in the tuple type. The problemo is that arg `n?: N` and `err?: Error` from Parameters do not appear to be being partitioned/considered in the `infer`, thus my conditional type lookup fails, and I'm out-of-luck.

My hack has been to `Required` wrap `Parameters<...>`, of which then I can successfully get the Body of the callback, and nicely reflect back a clean callback signature to the return value of `promisify(fn)(args) => Promise<WellTypedTupleArgsFromCallback>`.

One big exception--`WellTypedTupleArgsFromCallback` is now a tuple where *everything is guaranteed* because of the `Required`, which is a dishonest type.

This is very easy to see at work in the attached playground, and has some tests to show what is correct/incorrect.

**How can I correctly map the variadic callback Body with optional elements?**

Answer (score 1):

Lucky for me, I made an error in my assumptions. Node callback style is (err, ...values), not the inverse. It's been so long since using node callback style, that I forgot the correct signature ;).

This correct arg layout forces typing on the err as null/undefined/Error/unknown from user space, and removes the lack of discrimination on the optional args.

[updated playground with corrected solution and nomenclature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=47&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAE2AMwIYFcA29noHYDGMAlhHnGFBALbEDOxyAngDwAqcoMweCdcAMTwB1YjAAWAYQBGAPgAUMCAAUqtBswBccNgEo4AbwCwAKDhwYTMMDgy4AXjgAZVHRgtlqKKmrBuUOnZZWQBuU3NLa1tpAEEoAHN%20R09vX39AmVDwuCg-dChyXEISMjhXVRp6YHkAOjqvRNEJCHQYGW0AIQgEVhSfP2AAoNldbQr1YHZUYkwWGTjE4MNs8wIyNzgAbQa6AF0HCi8SErwXN3kdpvEWtuldMLNzHLyCuDxgAHc4car5IqJSOR5Lk6BBMAA3YAAGmeACtgER9MZHk84AB6NEWfgEVB4PAQeB4LxUL4CaRXGQAcn4%20EBcDWUFyREwTDguEwmDgH2AHJqZTwrOAdBx1gAhCsnooVGp6IxWa5%20UxdLV6gk6DD-ic4GQZCqagRYmrtPM1UiJai1ngNptBlAYXUaiCsDA9gcDQs6A9UajbXAAPxwhEweS2-TaEFgyHAoXO-gK3FKr3egC%209wlqaTyYeydMuZMaIAVAWdABRADKbDLcALaNMlo23DcAnwAHl3ib4gcLto8OhqNJBjCDdoQ4ye1hOQAfOAlxnQGHScf9wf6eyyODgiDEBCr9cG%20S9jkw1BwADUcAAjGmTPX4I2YM28G3gB3lAdKJUNExFEKH6324a8S6KY96Ps%20r7yAArLoNQSDw8jyJsvbULsu5vH2Dj2I4ABs%20gYuh1BwPQFhWDYyEDlA4omHW6x3r%20j5sB8EAdnQLZgPAjjdgRFFDoucCjlA2izlQUBwNOh6YDCdAAI5Ljx9I0L4eAwH62huFAxB4EBDjrpu25ofuEkwgAsqgEg1JAHwXDCABMugwgARGsYIOdet4WPR%20CMcxgGsexb6OB%206hyj%20TZeUxLFsTAwEmKB4U%20R6UXKPIdmweI8GITJQ7oAOqE6XAMmYY4AAscAAGRlfSOU2FhjhORALkxYWxZsOWlbVrW1Fde5YBHGIgJnBxbL4ACpTsJwIDcLwcYCpsuwKDs2h6MsjzudI3Sso4mwOjs%20wKmwSbuTAnKOOtPQWRAYDyNe5i5DA%20TkJsZ1MDCx1lPwg1BHt2K0dmDymKAkCwCRUQABLAKgCBBAcHBcDwfBbJpyCDHA4OQ-adRIyjAD6bDTJg%20wBmjCBwD2wCQlADyA9Ad6kTo%20PQ44sOTfD-CbFjonY8TGM1Bz9MzIT-OcmTFNU%20ANMgzYXQ9IzOgTVNCPbZjeDI6JHQwnzTiCx0pNvOTgxi0DtNRJ9bDrkz8us1sDp89LL1ESrKNa-6zi6%208ot5tTwORDYQhdjtRqKnNaEJobEs%204IIhiFI0gONk04IcOkchwKMXmAnFwJAADNoCa8doQgp0q8f8Zn8Q54qx4JBeucCvnyf5QmadiaXDQV3nZTV7X9sNDZ3f14XjepyXCFt-3nfxDXlcT3308NAAzOPSeD2uirNxnY9z13W-xLPHcL%20PDTFUvfEr%20uTcPEAA)